# How do i update element in Json String in java?

Tags: java, json

I want to update value of "status" and "amount"
Json String

```
{  
     "installmentno":"1",
     "receiptid":"",
     "duedate":"12-10-2016",
     "paymentdate":"",
     "amount":"3000.00",
     "status":"unpaid"
}
```

Comment: ... aaaaand... have you tried anything?

Comment: Convert to a JSON object, put the data in, convert back to string

Comment: Do you want to convert the string to an object, or do you just want to replace the value in the JSON string?

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way is convert Json to object, change values, and convert again to String Json:

Other methods:

1. If exists only one occurence of value in Json String, and you know current value, use: `String.replace("oldValue", "newValue");`
2. Use 
   `String.replaceAll("regex", "newValue");` 
   and regular expression
3. Use some external library e.g.: https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java.